# What is the location of the file for Windows 10 System Settings?

Tags: windows-10, default-settings

When I run `ms-settings:\\system` from an elevated prompt, I get a pop up that tells me the media is write protected. I expect that if I change the file's ownership to me (I am the owner of the system) I'll be able to open the settings.

What is the location of the file for Windows 10 System Settings?

Comment: If I run that on my windows 10 system, I get an error indicating that its not a valid path or program. Trying to cd to it tells me that the path doesn't exist. Can you share the exact commands you enter in a command prompt, and which version of Windows 10 you are using?

Comment: Open cmd as administrator. Once yo have the corresponding window type "start ms-settings:\\system"

Comment: Another way, like Ryan Bruce's answer implies, Win+X ms-settings:system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I Win+X and choose "System" I am taken to the System "About" page. Is that what you're looking for?

If so, you use ms-settings:about to access this page. Note: these are technically URIs rather than files, but the filepath to the actual systems application itself (which does nothing if you double-click, by the way) is %Windir%\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe

Here is the complete list of URI commands available from Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#system

To run one of these URIs, I used Win+R rather than an elevated command line.